# <input type="file" recebendo apenas valor null

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

estou com dificuldade meu projeto, tenho um campo em meu form onde passo um arquivo para o mesmo e envio para meu controller, problema é que o valor sempre chega null, já tentei varias formas mas, não estou achando meu erro, poderiam me dar uma força.

minha view

```html
@model WebApplication11.Models.Remessa

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Upload de Arquivos</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Candidato", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="well">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td>Arquivo : </td>
                <td><input type="file" asp-for="Arquivo" name="arq" multiple /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar Arquivo" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@ViewBag.Mensagem</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace WebApplication11.Models
{
    public class Remessa
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase Arquivo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Remessa arq)
    {
        try
        {
            string nomeArquivo = "";
            string arquivoEnviados = "";

                if (arq.Arquivo.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    nomeArquivo = Path.GetFileName(arq.Arquivo.FileName);
                    var caminho = Path.Combine("~/Imagens", nomeArquivo);
                arq.Arquivo.SaveAs(caminho);
                }

                arquivoEnviados = arquivoEnviados + " , " + nomeArquivo;

            ViewBag.Mensagem = "Arquivos enviados  : " + arquivoEnviados + " , com sucesso.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Mensagem = "Erro : " + ex.Message;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: do jeito que você fez provavelmente você vai encontrar seu arquivo dentro do Request.Files

Comment: Ola lucas, obrigado pela sua atenção mas, quando eu coloco Resquest.Files surgi erro dizendo que HttpRequest não contem uma definição para files =/....

Comment: não me refiro ao httprequest, mas ao httpcontext.request -> https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.request?view=netframework-4.8